# How can I convert a UTF-16 encoded string to an encoding suitable for a Mac OS X filename?

Tags: python, macos, utf-8, utf-16

I have a Localized.strings (UTF-16) file that contains some strings that I use to generate filenames for.  I open the file in python with `codecs.open("Localized.strings", "r", "utf-16")`

The files are created successfully but with a '?' tacked onto the end of the filename, for example:

MainMenu.strings? - where the "?" is lingering from the previous encoding I assume.

I've tried `filename_string.encode('UTF-8')` and `filename_string.encode('ascii')` with no luck, any suggestions?  Am I using these wrong?

Comment: You sure it's not the trailing \r or \n of reading those names from a file?

Comment: @pyroscope I have this strange habit of missing stuff like this. I'm almost certain this is the issue now that you've brought it up.  I'll be checking this tomorrow.

Comment: @pyroscope, if you write that comment as the answer I'll select it.  Turns out the filename needed a `strip()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, when reading lines from a file, it's advisable to always strip() or rstrip() them. :)